# Create class Employee and Get all employees to a GridView using SELECT

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-access-layer

I have Employee class and List of employee as you see below but I get blank ASP.NET page. No GridView shows and I'am not geting any error messsage either.
What's wrong I'am doing?

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { set; get; }
    public string FirstName { set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
}
```

And employeeelist

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
{
    try
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            empList = new List<Employee>();

            string sqlSelectString = "SELECT * FROM Employee";
            command = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectString, conn);
            command.Connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Employee emp = new Employee();
                emp.EmployeeId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID"));
                emp.FirstName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName"));
                emp.LastName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("LastName"));

                empList.Add(emp);
            }
            command.Connection.Close();
            return empList;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    return null;

}
```

Then in pageLoading

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    List<Employee> employeeList;

    employeeList = employee.GetEmployeeList();
    GridView1.DataSource = employeeList;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Att last my Gridview:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Clearly something is going wrong.  Place a `Debug.Print` after each record read and see if anything appears in the output during a debug session

Comment: @fnostro , thank you Fnostro... I found my own misstake.. ;) I have you use tostring() after every like  emp.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
emp.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["EmployeeId"].ToString());
emp.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
emp.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
```